# contiguous memory for passed in params

Tags: c, pointers, memory, parameters

I was trying something out and found out this little oddity. With the below piece of code it will output "World" (with each character broken onto each line). Does this mean parameters passed to functions are contiguous in memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void mystrtst(char *s, char *t);

int main() {
  mystrtst("Hello", "World");
}

void mystrtst(char *s, char *t) {
  while(*s++);
  for( ; *t ; s++, t++) {
    printf("%c\n", *s);
  };
}
```

Comment: Maybe this post can help you [Where are Parameter variables stored in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304705/where-are-parameter-variables-stored-in-memory).

Comment: In string literals, characters are stored contiguously.

Comment: The strings are not passed to the function, their addresses are. Since they are string literals, they probably reside in a read-only section in memory. Whether they are contiguous in that section is not mandated by the c-standard, i.e. you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: It makes sense for most implementations to work like this, but there's absolutely no guarantee that this code will work. It's non-standard behaviour, and I'm not aware of any compiler extensions that would guarantee string constants to be managed like this. In other words, it's UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pointers to 2 strings stored is some part of the memory.

What you are seeing is undefined behavior.

It is not guaranteed that these 2 strings will always be stored the way your output is showing.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gopi had said, it is an undefined behavior.
To understand it run this piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void mystrtst(char *s, char *t);

int main() {
  char s1[]="Hello";
  char  t1[]="World";
  mystrtst(s1, t1);
}

void mystrtst(char *s, char *t) {
  while(*s++);
  for( ; *t ; s++, t++) {
    printf("%c\n", *s);
  };
}
```

You will get some random characters showing that the parameters' memory is not contiguous. In fact you are passing the addresses only.

When you directly pass the parameters as `"Hello", "World"` it gets stored in read only memory and pointers to these memory addresses are passed, somehow the memory became contiguous in your case. Don't expect the same behavior every time. It is undefined.